# Default Django Admin Forms and FormWizard

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So, I want to use a default Django admin form in a form wizard, because there are a number of objects with foreign keys to the main object on both the first and second pages of this form, and I'd like to be able to edit them inline. I used the example at http://elo80ka.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/using-a-formwizard-in-the-django-admin/ as a base, however, he specifies his own form that he has the admin use. Of course, if you use your own custom form, inlines won't work with that. So, I tried doing the following:

```
create_syllabus = SyllabusCreationWizard([SyllabusAdmin.form, CalendarForm])
```

If I do so, however, I get the following error:

```
'ModelForm' object has no attribute '_meta'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Charybdis/syllabus/add/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'ModelForm' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in __init__, line 229
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
```

It would appear that the auto generated Admin form does not specify the class Meta information that a regular ModelForm is required to.

My question, then, is if there's any way to use the default admin form with the FormWizard. Do I need to somehow supply the Meta for the admin form, and if so how? Or do I need to be doing something else entirely?

Comment: How would you do it today, after 4 years? :)

Comment: Easy: I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a problem with how the form is created and used in the ModelAdmin.
If you call 'SyllabusAdmin.form' it will be the class ModelForm, uninitialized.

Afaik ModelAdmin uses get_form to actually create and configure the form.

In your case you would have to do something like

`form = SyllabusAdmin(SyllabusModel, admin.site).get_form(request)`

to achieve what you want... hope it answers your question.